# ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED on Android 9, with domain cleartext permitted

Tags: android, security, cleartext

On an Android 10 device, I get an ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED error in webview on my http server, but only on some pages, and even though I am using network_security_config to allow the domain.  I am only able to work around the error by opening up all domains using .  How can I fix this so only my domain is permitted, and not receive the error, but without using ?

Logcat:

```
07:54:09.004 com.myserver.myapp D/myapp: Webview.onPageStarted called on http://myserver.com/myapp/index.php?view=discrete
07:54:09.232 com.myserver.myapp I/myapp: onPageFinished called.
07:54:15.938 com.myserver.myapp D/myapp: Webview.onPageStarted called on http://myserver.com/myapp/index.php?view=about
07:54:15.958 com.myserver.myapp I/myapp: onReceivedError called.
07:54:15.958 com.myserver.myapp I/myapp: Web Load Error:net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED
07:54:16.012 com.myserver.myapp I/myapp: onPageFinished called.
```

Network-security-config xml:

```
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">myserver.com</domain>
</domain-config>
    <!-- Want to delete this for better security--> 
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Build is android 9 (SDK 28), device is android 10

Comment: Post `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Comment: If your page includes JavaScript, images, etc. from other sites, those might trigger this error. Are you sure that all of your page elements are covered by your `<domain>` elements?

Answer (score 0):

Root cause was that the javascript serving third party ad content (Google Ads) did not use https.

Added code to onReceivedError to log the URL that is causing the issue...

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            Log.i(TAG, "onReceivedError called for URL "+ request.getUrl().toString());
}
```